# Trying to import a file but AE imports the whole folder

Tags: after-effects

I am new to After Effects. I imported few images into a project before creating a composition and it worked fine. I am trying to import more files but AE is importing the whole folder and not able to choose any individual image. How to fix?

Comment: Are the files sequentially numbered, e.g. file1.png, file2.png and so on? If so, AE is assuming they're an image sequence. There's a checkbox in the import window that you can uncheck to stop this happening.

Comment: No they are not sequentially numbered. They have random names. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How are you doing the import?  Press cmd+I to open the import dialogue, or double click in the empty space inside the project frame.  Then select the files you need.

Comment: I have tried cmd+I, double click in the empty space inside the project frame and File > Import > File and also, File > Import > Multiple Files but all creating the same issue!! I have also tried closing AE completely and reopening it.